# C# WindowsApp TextBox with Special Characters

Tags: c#, textbox, richtextbox, special-characters

I would like to include a textbox / richtextbox in which I would like to include text such as

```
"jogħġbok żomm din il-bieb magħluq".
```

When I putting this text in the textbox/rightext box I am getting the following:

```
jog&#295;&#289;bok &#380;omm din il-bieb mag&#295;luq
```

Can you please help?

I am getting the string from google translate:

```
        string url = String.Format("http://www.google.com/translate_t?hl=en&ie=UTF8&text={0}&langpair={1}", 
            input, languagePair);
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        string result = webClient.DownloadString(url);
        result = result.Substring(result.IndexOf("<span title=\"") + "<span title=\"".Length);
        result = result.Substring(result.IndexOf(">") + 1);
        result = result.Substring(0, result.IndexOf("</span>"));
        return result.Trim();
```

**Edit:**

I would like to convert:

```
"jog&#295;&#289;bok &#380;omm din il-bieb mag&#295;luq"
```

to

```
"jogħġbok żomm din il-bieb magħluq"
```

Comment: This is a unicode problem. For some reason the text box isnt handling unicode right. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6270d0z.aspx may help. (thats all I know really!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can convert the html text with System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode:

```
        string str = "jog&#295;&#289;bok &#380;omm din il-bieb mag&#295;luq";
        str = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(str); 
        textBox1.Text = str;
        richTextBox1.Text = str;
```

Comment: thanks!!
For other that might have this problem, remember to add a reference to Systems.web

Comment: was just having the same problem, was about to post a question but I found this.  Thanks for being awesome!